# В чем разница при вызове переменных?

Tags: php

В чём разница использования следующих вызовов переменных? Как я понял, одни из них устарели и не безопасны, но в чём это заключается я так и не понял.

1. ```
   $names = fix_names("WILLIAM", "henry", "gatES");

   function fix_names($n1, $n2, $n3)
   {
       $n1 = ucfirst(strtolower($n1));
       $n2 = ucfirst(strtolower($n2));
       $n3 = ucfirst(strtolower($n3));
       return array($n1, $n2, $n3);
   }

   echo $names[0] . " " . $names[1] . " " . $names[2]."<br>";
   ```
2. ```
   $a1 = "WILLIAM";
   $a2 = "henry";
   $a3 = "gatES";

   function fix_names(&$n1, &$n2, &$n3)
   {
       $n1 = ucfirst(strtolower($n1));
       $n2 = ucfirst(strtolower($n2));
       $n3 = ucfirst(strtolower($n3));
   }

   echo $a1." ".$a2." ".$a3."<br>";

   fix_names($a1, $a2, $a3);
   echo $a1." ".$a2." ".$a3;
   ```
3. ```
   $a1 = "WILLIAM";
   $a2 = "henry";
   $a3 = "gatES";

   function fix_names()
   {
       global $a1; $a1 = ucfirst(strtolower($a1));
       global $a2; $a2 = ucfirst(strtolower($a2));
       global $a3; $a3 = ucfirst(strtolower($a3));
   }

   echo $a1." ".$a2." ".$a3."<br>";

   fix_names();
   echo $a1." ".$a2." ".$a3;
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый отличается от других тем, что он не портит переданные аргументы и является чистой функцией. Третий отличается от второго, тем что он знает, какие именно переменные надо менять и делает это самостоятельно.

Comment: Получается, что угроза безопасности остается и следует избегать подобный тип работы с переменными?

Comment: @Filimok, я не вижу уязвимостей ни в одном из трёх вариантов кода.

Answer (score 2):

Разницы тут нет, все три - это все какие-то извращенные способы работы с переменными. Ни один из них не является небезопасным или устарел, но они все просто неудобные. Последний, впрочем, все же хуже первых двух - после вызова функции переменные вдруг меняют свое значение, и непонятно по какой причине.

Проще всего сделать простую и понятную функцию и просто и понятно ее вызывать

```
function fix_name($n)
{
    return ucfirst(strtolower($n));
}

$a1 = "WILLIAM";
$a2 = "henry";
$a3 = "gatES";
echo fix_name($a1) . " " . fix_name($a2) . " " . fix_name($a3)."<br>";
```

Comment: "Ранее употребляли перед именем переменной символа &, который заставлял парсер передавать ссылку на переменную, а не значение самой переменной. Тем самым функции предоставлялся доступ к переменной (позволяющий записывать в нее различные значения), что могло создать угрозу безопасности.", как я понял сейчас такое убрали из php

Comment: В общем здесь я и запутался, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Filimok, нет, убрали `&` у вызывающего кода, а у функции всё на месте. Это если я ничего не путаю. Не программирую на php.

Comment: @Ипатьев, я бы сказал, что весьма сомнительный ответ.

Comment: @Filimok тебе надо немедленно выбросить эту книжку. Ее написал очень странный человек очень давно. Помимо просто глупостей, как эта, там написаны просто чудовищные вещи. Возьми лучше Котерова.

Comment: @Ипатьев Создаем динамические веб-сайты с помощью PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, CSS и HTML5. Серия бестселлеров O'Reilly. Не знаю на сколько актуальна книга, но пока что особых трудностей в понимании не возникает... Но это не единственная книга, которую я запланировал прочитать.

Comment: @Filimok ещё раз: Прошу прочесть мой комментарий внимательно, я больше повторять не буду. Я ничего не писал про "трудности". Я писал про глупости. Книга очень вредная, если учиться по ней, то на любом собеседовании тебя просто выгонят не дослушав.